# Why would one use nested classes?

Tags: swift, nest

Been doing objective-c for 5 years, so please bear with me.

I'm struggling to find documentation that clearly explains why you would want to nest a class definition, inside of another.

If I had two classes like the following, it makes sense to me that they are declared above and below each other. You may even want to have a nested property that references the other.

```
class DataImporter {
     }

class DataGenerator {
     }
```

But I don't understand why a nested arrangement like the following would be useful.

```
class DataImporter {
     class DataGenerator {
     } }
```

Comment: If the inner class is used **only** by the outer class for its own purposes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would do that for Namespacing. This way you can have the classes with the same name (like `DataGenerator`). But for different purposes. This one would be `DataImporter.DataGenerator` class, but you could have another `OtherClass.DataGenerator` class which would be a totally different one.

Like in Objective-C when you had 2 or 3 letters before the name of the class (ex: `UIView`). But when you created your own, it would be like `SSView`

You can also declare the inner class private and use it just in that file.

Comment: Yes, they do. This is just an additional way to do it within a module. You might want to have the classes with the same name in one module. Also declaring a class as private allows you to use it within that file, but it makes it invisible to other files.