# Swift syntax issue: Nested class type cannot be used when declaring variables of that type

Tags: ios, swift, syntax

Rather than call my pin class 'EventMapViewPin', I thought I would nest the class like so.

```
class EventMapView: MKMapView {

    class Pin: MapPin {

        var event: Event!

        convenience init(event: Event, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, title: String, subtitle: String) {
            self.init(coordinate: coordinate, title: title, subtitle: subtitle)
        }

    }

}

class MapPin: NSObject, MKAnnotation {

    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var title: String?
    var subtitle: String?

    init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, title: String, subtitle: String) {
        self.coordinate = coordinate
        self.title = title
        self.subtitle = subtitle
    }

}
```

But I can't use the class in this context.

```
var collector = [EventMapView.Pin]()
```

**Error: Invalid use of '()' to call a function of non-function type**

As a follow on from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35947901/1951992), I'm surprised to see that this syntax is illegal. How would I declare a variable of type [EventMapView.Pin], when the classes are nested in this namespace conscious way?

Answer (score 1):

You can initialise the array in the following way:

```
 var collector = Array<EventMapView.Pin>()
```

Comment: using typealias is another kind of workaround